# What does "setData('used_in_forms')" stand for in SQL install

Tags: magento-1.9

I am creating a custom customer attribute.

```
<?php
$this->addAttribute('customer', 'complaining_customer', array(
    'input'        => 'text',
    'type'         => 'varchar',
    'label'        => 'Special ATT',
    'position'     => 120,
    'user_defined' => 0,
    'required'     => false,

));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'complaining_customer');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);   
$attribute->save();
```

I don't want this attribute to be visible to the customer.

I noticed that under `$attribute->setData`
I have `'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit'`

I was wondering if that means that this attribute might appear somewhere in the frontend. Should I remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setting adds this attribute field on the collection data to be **loaded** when those pages are loaded.

The frontend theme you are using *is unlikely* to be auto-generating the '`checkout_register`', '`customer_account_create`', '`customer_account_edit`' forms for the user.

The fields in these forms are specified in the templates individually.

So, in general, all such custom created attribute values will not be *visible* to the user in any of those forms. Unless you explicitly add them, in those respective templates.

The backend does auto-generate the forms using whatever available fields it received from the collection.